# ReactNative rerenders component when the user opens the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two components the first where user can add a place to the favorites and the second is favorites component where user may see all his favorite places. When the user for the first time opens the favorites component everything works as expected: all the favorite places that user has already added to the favorites rendered. But if user go to the first component and add one more place and then go to the second component new place will not appear because component has already rendered and the state didn't changed because useEffect not triggered. Help me please what should I use in my FavouritePlaces component instead of useEffect to rerender this component every time when user open FavouritePlaces?

Component where user can add to favorites:

```
const ModalWindow = ({navigateToPlace, sendDataToParent, visible, marker}: HomeNavigationProps<"ModalWindow">) => {
    const regex = /(<([^>]+)>)|(&nbsp;)|(&nbps)/ig;
    const result = marker.description.replace(regex, '');
    const [favKeys, setFavKeys] = useState([]);
    const onDismiss = () => {
        sendDataToParent(false)
    }
    const onNavigationTap = () => {
        onDismiss();
        navigateToPlace(true, marker.coordinates);
    }
    const getFavourites = async () => {
        let keys = []
        keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()
        setFavKeys(keys);
    }
    const onHeartPress = async () => {
        const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(marker)
        try {
            if (favKeys.includes(marker.id.toString())){
                await AsyncStorage.removeItem(marker.id.toString())
                await getFavourites();
            } else {
                await AsyncStorage.setItem(marker.id.toString(), jsonValue)
                await getFavourites();
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('error in onHeartPress', e)
        }
        console.log('Done.')
        //remove after test
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.removeItem('__react_native_storage_test')
        } catch(e) {
            // remove error
        }
        console.log('Done.')
    }
    return (
        <Modal visible={visible} onDismiss={onDismiss} contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
            <IconButton
                style={
                    styles.iconButton
                }
                icon="close"
                color={Colors.black}
                size={30}
                onPress={() => onDismiss()}
            />
            <Text
                style={{fontStyle: "italic", fontSize: 20, alignSelf: "center", maxWidth: '75%'}}>{marker.title}
            </Text>
            <CustomCarousel {...{marker}} />
            <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} style={{marginTop: '3%', marginLeft: '3%', marginRight: '3%'}}>
                <Text>{result}</Text>
            </ScrollView>
            <View style={{flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-around", marginLeft: "3%", marginRight: "3%", marginBottom: "15%"}}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onNavigationTap()}>
                    <View style={{flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center"}}>
                        <Ionicons size={height/20} name={'navigate-circle-outline'} />
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onHeartPress()}>
                {marker.id ?
                    <View style={{flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center"}}>
                    {favKeys.includes(marker.id.toString()) ? <Ionicons size={height/20} name={'heart-dislike'} /> : <Ionicons size={height/20} name={'heart'} />}
                </View> : undefined}
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </Modal>
    );
}

export default ModalWindow;
```

My Favorite Places component:

```
const FavouritePlaces = ({navigation}: HomeNavigationProps<"FavouritePlaces">) => {
    const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const getFavourites = async () => {
            let keys = []
            try {
                keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()
            } catch (e) {
                // read key error
            }
            let values
            try {
                let forDeletion = ['__react_native_storage_test', 'NAVIGATION_STATE_KEY-40.0.0'];
                keys = keys.filter(item => !forDeletion.includes(item))
                values = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys)
                setMarkers(values)
            } catch (e) {
                // read error
            }
        }
        getFavourites();
    }, [])
    const transition = (
        <Transition.Together>
            <Transition.Out type='fade'/>
            <Transition.In type='fade'/>
        </Transition.Together>
    );

    const list = useRef<TransitioningView>(null);
    const theme = useTheme()
    const width = (wWidth - theme.spacing.m * 3) / 2;
    const [footerHeight, setFooterHeight] = useState(0);
    return (
        <Box flex={1} backgroundColor="background">
            <StatusBar style="black" />
            <Header
                title="Избранные места"
                left={{icon: 'menu', onPress: () => navigation.openDrawer()}}
                right={{icon: 'shopping-bag', onPress: () => true}}
            />
            <Box flex={1}>
                <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} contentContainerStyle={{
                    paddingBottom: footerHeight,

                }}>
                    <Transitioning.View ref={list} transition={transition} style={{}}>
                        {markers ?
                            <Box flexDirection='row' style={{justifyContent: "space-around"}}>
                                <Box>
                                    {markers
                                        .filter((_, i) => i % 2 === 0).map((currentMarker) => <Picture
                                            key={currentMarker}
                                            place={currentMarker}
                                            width={width}
                                            height={height}
                                        />)}
                                </Box>
                                <Box>
                                    {markers
                                        .filter((_, i) => i % 2 !== 0).map((currentMarker) => <Picture
                                            key={currentMarker}
                                            place={currentMarker}
                                            width={width}
                                            height={height}/>)}
                                </Box>
                            </Box> : undefined}
                    </Transitioning.View>
                </ScrollView>
                {/*<TopCurve footerHeight={footerHeight}/>*/}
                <Box position='absolute' bottom={0} left={0} right={0} onLayout={({
                                                                                      nativeEvent: {
                                                                                          layout: {height},
                                                                                      }
                                                                                  }) => setFooterHeight(height)}>                               
                </Box>
            </Box>
        </Box>
    )
}
export default FavouritePlaces
```

Comment: Is `AsyncStorage` required? If not you can achieve this "shared" state by using the Context API.

Comment: @karlmarxlopez I think AsyncStorage is not required if I can get all favorite places in another way. But maybe I should in ModalWindow component after adding place to the favorites every time get all the places from AsyncStorage and using Context API send places to the Favorites component? But I tend to think that if user opens the application and opens the favorites without adding new than Context will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. React navigation has hook `useIsFocused`, so what can we do is:

```
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";
const isFocused = useIsFocused();
useEffect(() => {
    // ... Your code goes here
}, [isFocused]);
```

Comment: Or, you can just use `useFocuseEffect`.

Comment: @karlmarxlopez before this solution I tried `useFocusEffect` but the thing is it rerenders my component in a loop when I'm on the Favorites screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 useEffect(() => {
    // ... Your code goes here
}, [navigation]);
```

this will render whenever update in navigate

Answer (score 0):

You can use React Context API to share the state across the screens.

Check out this [Expo Snack I created.](https://snack.expo.io/@iamkarlmarx/favorite-places)

```
import {
  CompositeNavigationProp,
  NavigationContainer,
  NavigatorScreenParams,
} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  StackNavigationProp,
} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  FlatList,
  ListRenderItem,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

type MainStackParamsList = {
  FavoritePlacesScreen: undefined;
};

type ModalStackParamsList = {
  MainStack: NavigatorScreenParams<MainStackParamsList>;
  AddFavoritePlacesModal: undefined;
};

type FavoritePlace = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
};

type FavoritePlacesContextValue = {
  favoritePlaces: FavoritePlace[];
  addNewFavoritePlace: (favoritePlace: FavoritePlace) => void;
  removeFavoritePlace: (id: number) => void;
};

const FavoritePlacesContext = React.createContext<FavoritePlacesContextValue>({
  favoritePlaces: [],
  addNewFavoritePlace: () => {},
  removeFavoritePlace: () => {},
});

const MainStack = createStackNavigator<MainStackParamsList>();

type FavoritePlacesScreenProps = {
  navigation: CompositeNavigationProp<
    StackNavigationProp<MainStackParamsList, 'FavoritePlacesScreen'>,
    StackNavigationProp<ModalStackParamsList>
  >;
};

const FavoritePlacesScreen = ({navigation}: FavoritePlacesScreenProps) => {
  const {favoritePlaces, removeFavoritePlace} = React.useContext(
    FavoritePlacesContext,
  );

  const renderItem = React.useCallback<ListRenderItem<FavoritePlace>>(
    ({item}) => {
      return (
        <View style={{height: 50, padding: 10, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 16}}>{item.name}</Text>
          <Button onPress={() => removeFavoritePlace(item.id)} title="Remove" />
        </View>
      );
    },
    [removeFavoritePlace],
  );

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <FlatList
        data={favoritePlaces}
        keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.id)}
        renderItem={renderItem}
      />
      <Button
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate('AddFavoritePlacesModal');
        }}
        title="Add new favorite"
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const MainStackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <MainStack.Navigator>
      <MainStack.Screen
        component={FavoritePlacesScreen}
        name="FavoritePlacesScreen"
      />
    </MainStack.Navigator>
  );
};

type AddFavoritePlacesModalProps = {
  navigation: StackNavigationProp<
    ModalStackParamsList,
    'AddFavoritePlacesModal'
  >;
};

const AddFavoritePlacesModal = ({navigation}: AddFavoritePlacesModalProps) => {
  const {addNewFavoritePlace} = React.useContext(FavoritePlacesContext);

  const [favoritePlaceName, setFavoritePlaceName] = React.useState('');

  const handleOnSave = React.useCallback(() => {
    addNewFavoritePlace({
      id: Date.now(),
      name: favoritePlaceName,
    });
    navigation.goBack();
  }, [addNewFavoritePlace, favoritePlaceName, navigation]);

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <View style={{borderRadius: 6, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#333'}}>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={setFavoritePlaceName}
          placeholder="Name your favorite place"
        />
      </View>
      <Button onPress={handleOnSave} title="Save" />
    </View>
  );
};

// Put the favorite places list screen and the add favorite place modal here.
// Then use FavoritePlacesContext.Provider to wrap ModalStack.Navigator in order
// for the context to be available on MainStack
const ModalStack = createStackNavigator<ModalStackParamsList>();

const ModalNavigator = () => {
  const [favoritePlaces, setFavoritePlaces] = React.useState<FavoritePlace[]>(
    [],
  );

  const addNewFavoritePlace = React.useCallback(
    (favoritePlace: FavoritePlace) => {
      setFavoritePlaces((prev) => [...prev, favoritePlace]);
    },
    [],
  );

  const removeFavoritePlace = React.useCallback((id: number) => {
    setFavoritePlaces((prev) =>
      prev.filter((favoritePlace) => favoritePlace.id !== id),
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <FavoritePlacesContext.Provider
      value={{
        favoritePlaces,
        addNewFavoritePlace,
        removeFavoritePlace,
      }}
    >
      <ModalStack.Navigator headerMode="none">
        <ModalStack.Screen component={MainStackNavigator} name="MainStack" />
        <ModalStack.Screen
          component={AddFavoritePlacesModal}
          name="AddFavoritePlacesModal"
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
      </ModalStack.Navigator>
    </FavoritePlacesContext.Provider>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <ModalNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```